# Action method is :id with link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to subscribe to a product by clicking the link:

```
<%= link_to "Subscribe", :controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id, :method => :post %>
```

I get this error and notice the parameters are wrong.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#show

Couldn't find Product with id=subscribe_product

{"id"=>"subscribe_product", "method"=>"post"}
```

My subscribe_product method in my ProductsController is:

```
def subscribe_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.subscriptions.create(:subscriber_id => current_user.id)
end
```

My route:

```
resources :products do
  post :subscribe_product, :on => :collection
end
```

These are the associations:

```
class User
  has_many :products
  has_many :subscriptions, :foreign_key => :subscriber_id

class Product
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :subscriptions, :as => :subscribable

class Subscriptions
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :subscribable, :polymorphic => true
```

Users subscribe in another controller:

```
PagesController
  def index
   @product_history = current_user.products
  end
end

pages/index.html.erb

<% for product in @product_history %>
  <%= product.name %>
  <%= product.price %>
  <%= link_to "Subscribe", :controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id, :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

So why is my action method being seen as the ID instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing an `id`, the `subscribe_product` route should be a `member` route. Try this, and let me know what you get:

```
resources :products do
  member do
    post 'subscribe_product'
  end
end
```

In the controller (to get around non-mass-assignable attributes):

```
def subscribe_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  subscription = Subscription.new
  subscription.subscriber_id = current_user.id
  @product.subscriptions << subscription
end
```

Comment: When using my first link_to: `<%= link_to "Subscribe", :controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id, :method => :post %>`, It gives the the error - `No route matches [GET] "/products/5/subscribe_product"`

Comment: I think your link needs to look like this (separate hash for the path): `<%= link_to "Subscribe", {:controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id}, :method => :post %>`. If that doesn't work, can you run `rake routes | grep subscribe_product` and let me know what you get.

Comment: I think its working but I noticed I have a `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: subscriber_id, subscribable_type`, so I wouldn't be sure of it. I don't want these to be available as mass assignable. Right now I get `Template Missing` but I can just redirect effectively.

Comment: That just means you can't create them with a hash in your controller. I'll update my answer to show you how it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
resources :products do
  post :subscribe_product, :on => :member
end
```

It will generate routes like :

```
subscribe_product_product POST     /product/:id/subscribe_product(.:format)   {:action=>"subscribe_product", :controller=>"products"}
```

and use path like in view :

```
subscribe_products_path(product.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Change your route to :

```
resources :products do
  post :subscribe
end
```

Then change your link like :

```
<%= link_to "Subscribe", subscribe_products_path(:id => product.id), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: This gives me a NoMethodError because the products being viewed are in a different controller. Not sure how to deal with this. I will edit my answer and show the controller and view.

Comment: what kind of no method error ? on which method ? Please try subscribe_products_path instead, i made an a mistake on the order of the named route :P

Comment: I had to make it `post :subscribe, :on => :collection` but then I get the error `Couldn't find Product without an ID`.

Comment: `Template missing`, That's a new one! It thinks the `subscribe` method is a view now.

Comment: That is because you are not redirecting somewhere in your subscribe controller method. If you add a 'redirect_to products_path' it will redirect to that page. I would highly recommend reading a book about Rails, to get a better grasp on how to work with it.